# Parse HTTP Request Line In C

Tags: c, parsing, request, webserver, httprequest

This is the problem that will never end. The task is to parse a request line in a web server -- of indeterminate length -- in C. I pulled the following off of the web as an example with which to work.

```
GET /path/script.cgi?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.1
```

I must extract the absolute path: `/path/script.cgi` and the query: `?field1=value1&field2=value2`. I'm told the following functions hold the key: `strchr`, `strcpy`, `strncmp`, `strncpy`, and/or `strstr`.

Here's what has happened so far: I've learned that using functions like `strchr` and `strstr` will absolutely allow me to truncate the request line at certain points, but will never allow me to get rid of portions of the request line I do not want, and it doesn't matter how I layer them.

For example, here's some code that get's me close to isolating the query, but I can't eliminate the http version.

```
bool parse(const char* line)
{
    // request line w/o method
    const char ch = '/';
    char* lineptr = strchr(line, ch);

    // request line w/ query and HTTP version
    char ch_1 = '?';
    char* lineptr_1 = strchr(lineptr, ch_1);

    // request line w/o query
    char ch_2 = ' ';
    char* lineptr_2 = strchr(lineptr_1, ch_2);

    printf("%s\n", lineptr_2);

    if (lineptr_2 != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Needless to say, I have a similar issue trying to isolate the absolute path (I can ditch the method, but not the ? or anything thereafter), and I see no occasion on which I can use the functions that require me to know *a priori* how many chars I'd like to copy from one location (usually an array) to another because, when this is run in real time, I will have no clue what the request line will look like in advance. If someone sees something that I am missing and could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful!

Comment: Why not write your own function to parse up to a symbol, whitespace, or newline? You could then use that function to grab the absolute path (parse up to the first '?' or '\n' or ' ') and use the same function again, with the starting index being the index of the last character of the absolute path plus 1, to grab the query string.

Comment: A sound idea, and I may have to do that. Of course, the last time I tried I ended up reinventing strcpy. lol

Comment: That's the beauty of programming, especially in low-level languages such as C. If something you need doesn't exist, you can create it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more elegant solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int parse(const char* line)
{
    /* Find out where everything is */
    const char *start_of_path = strchr(line, ' ') + 1;
    const char *start_of_query = strchr(start_of_path, '?');
    const char *end_of_query = strchr(start_of_query, ' ');

    /* Get the right amount of memory */
    char path[start_of_query - start_of_path];
    char query[end_of_query - start_of_query];

    /* Copy the strings into our memory */
    strncpy(path, start_of_path,  start_of_query - start_of_path);
    strncpy(query, start_of_query, end_of_query - start_of_query);

    /* Null terminators (because strncpy does not provide them) */
    path[sizeof(path)] = 0;
    query[sizeof(query)] = 0;

    /*Print */
    printf("%s\n", query, sizeof(query));
    printf("%s\n", path, sizeof(path));
}

int main(void)
{
    parse("GET /path/script.cgi?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.1");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. There's a lot to unpack here. It looks like you're performing pointer subtraction. I wasn't aware you could do that in C. Should I assume the char array lengths of 60 are arbitrary? Or is there a convention I am unaware of?

Comment: I should have added more commentary, my bad. the 60 was arbitrary. You can actually get the right amount of memory by also using pointer subtraction... let me make some edits.

Comment: To add to this conversation, you can certainly perform pointer arithmetic in C. Keeping in mind that each pointer is essentially a memory address and pointers to arrays reference sequential data, you can add to the memory address an offset equal to the size of the type referenced by the pointer. That being said, be careful not to perform pointer arithmetic on pointers of different types because they may not be aligned appropriately. The compiler can translate decimal values such as "1,2,3" into the appropriate pointer offset, however, so you need not worry about things such as "line+4".

Comment: I think I should also note that it isn't guaranteed that the start_of_path will be line + 4 (what if someone is performing an HTTP POST?).

Comment: Good point. For my purposes, it will always be GET. Some of the code not show here checks for things like that and rejects all POST requests. In real life, however, it would have to handle both cases.

Comment: @RyanD. just added POST compatibility.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar a nice solution you have provided. I like how you referenced a known library with built in capacity to perform the task while my answer shows how someone could write the functions to do it themselves. Nice variety.

Comment: This is really good stuff and both you and @CaitLANJenner gave me quite a bit to think about. Nice change from banging my head against a wall for the last several days and getting nowhere. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote some functions in C a while back that manually parse c-strings up to a delimiter, similar to getline in C++.

```
// Trims all leading whitespace along with consecutive whitespace from provided cstring into destination char*. WARNING: ensure size <= sizeof(destination)
void Trim(char* destination, char* source, int size)
{
    bool trim = true;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (source[i] == '\n' || source[i] == '\0')
        {
            destination[index++] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        else if (source[i] != ' ' && source[i] != '\t')
        {
            destination[index++] = source[i];
            trim = false;
        }
        else if (trim)
            continue;
        else
        {
            if (index > 0 && destination[index - 1] != ' ')
                destination[index++] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

// Parses text up to the provided delimiter (or newline) into the destination char*. WARNING: ensure size <= sizeof(destination)
void ParseUpToSymbol(char* destination, char* source, int size, char delimiter)
{
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (source[i] != delimiter && source[i] != '\n' && source[i] != '\0'  && source[i] != ' '))
        {
            destination[index++] = source[i];
        }
        else
        {
            destination[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    Trim(destination, destination, size);
}
```

Then you could parse your c-string with something along these lines:

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(64);
char* temp = (char*)malloc(256);
strcpy(temp, "GET /path/script.cgi?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.1");
Trim(temp, temp, 256);
ParseUpToSymbol(buffer, cstr, 64, '?');
temp = temp + strlen(buffer) + 1;
Trim(temp, temp, 256);
```

The code above trims any leading and trailing whitespace from the target string, in this case "GET /path/script.cgi?field1=value1&field2=value2 HTTP/1.1", and then stores the parsed value into the variable buffer. Running this the first time should put the word "GET" inside of buffer. When you do the "temp = temp + strlen(buffer) + 1" you are readjusting the temp char-pointer so you can call ParseUpToSymbol again with the remaining part of the string.  If you were to call it again, you should get the absolute path leading up to the first question mark. You could repeat this to get each individual query string or change the delimiter to a space and get the entire query string portion of the URL. I think you get the idea.  This is just one of many solutions of course.

Comment: Many Thanks! I'll give this a thorough going over. It certainly seems like the type of thing I might need, since I absolutely need to parse up to a symbol or space, as the case may be.  Appreciate you sharing this!

Comment: Anytime. I hope this works for you - and by all means feel free to modify it as you see fit (also please reply if you find any errors and I'll address them). This is a bit of code I wrote for some C projects I was working on a while back where I ended up in a similar dilemma of not having the library functions available that I needed.  You could always use some interesting format specifiers with sscanf() but sometimes it is nice to use your own routine and avoid over-complicating the code.